# How to find referer in php on OpenShift?

Tags: php, apache, openshift

I have an application which needs visitor's referer in order to work properly.
I am using **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];** to find the referer, but this doesn't seem to work on Openshift, since Openshift's proxy removes the referer variable set by the user.

Comment: To which version of openshift do your refer? On which platform do you run your php??

Comment: It seems to work for me when tested on OpenShift Online current gen (v2) and next gen dev preview (v3). Maybe the thing is that you can't really [trust the user agent to set the referer](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)?